Disable Button shape accessibility from programming
Is there any way to disable button shape accessibility from app code?
Because it shows greyish backgorund all over the app which kill UI part.
The tabs & all buttons show grey background all the places like following:

I search to remove this using button style keep as plain or use custom button,
but I have to change all over the app using central coding instead of doing one-by-one button.
Thank you,

Could you share the code and steps to reproduce the issue you're facing? I never saw this gray-around area in a Button using SwiftUI. Is there an accessibility preference that has to be set in order to see this?

If you are not using a common subclass of UIButton, then you can probably write a method in UIButton extension and use that method all over the place.

Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit (the question has both tags)? For SwiftUI, you can apply your own ButtonStyle. Or you could avoid using Button altogether. See the answer to How to create a reusable button component in SwiftUI? for details.

@WallaceSilva, yes it uses accessibility preference "Button Shape"

If you are using SwiftUI then button shapes can be prevented by applying a custom ButtonStyle. As a quick fix for your purposes, you could use a button style that simply returns the label without additional styling:
struct BasicButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}

If this button style is applied at the top level then it will take effect for all buttons that are not already using a button style:
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {} label: {
            Text("Submit")
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                .padding(.vertical, 6)
                .background(.blue)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
    }
    .buttonStyle(BasicButtonStyle())
}

A cleaner solution would be to move the styling into a custom button style, but this will mean updating all the buttons affected:
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(.horizontal, 40)
            .padding(.vertical, 6)
            .background(.blue)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Submit") {}
    }
    .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
}

